# SARIMAX Rolling Window with exogen Variables

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, forecasting

at the moment i am trying to build a SARIMAX Model in python with exogen variables.
Unfortunately i am getting this error: "cannot perform reduce with flexible type"

```
# Function for Rolling Forecast with Sarima
def rolling_forecast(traindata,test_data, Modell_order = None , Sarima_order = None, eliminate_0 = True, exogen= None, exogen_test=None):
    history = [x for x in traindata]
    history_exogen = [x for x in exogen]
    predictions = list()
  
    for t in range(len(test_data)):
        Sarima_Modell_same = SARIMAX(history,order = Modell_order ,seasonal_order= Sarima_order, exog=history_exogen)
        model_fit = Sarima_Modell_same.fit()
        output = model_fit.forecast(steps = 1,exog=history_exogen)
        
        yhat = output[0]
        obs = test_data[t]
        obs_ex = exogen_test[t]
        predictions.append(yhat)
        history.append(obs)
        history_exogen.append(obs_ex)
        #print('predicted=%f, expected=%f' % (yhat, obs))
    
    series_predicted = pd.Series(predictions, dtype='float64')
    series_predicted.index = test_data.index

    if eliminate_0 is True:
        # Eliminate 0 values --> (for differenced Time Series not applyable because of negativ values)
        series_predicted = series_predicted.apply(lambda x : x if x > 0 else 0)
        test_data.plot()
        series_predicted.plot(color = 'red')
    else:
        test_data.plot()
        series_predicted.plot(color = 'red')

    #print(sqrt(mean_squared_error(test_data, series_predicted)))
    

    
Is there any way to do this?
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This might be a good time for you to practice your debug skills. The following three references give excellent advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)

Comment: I already implemented the univariate Forecast with SARIMA but with the SARIMAX Model i dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Ist More about the multivariate Part. Without the exogen variable it is working but if i try to include it the error appears.
Would appreciate any help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).